# Logstash doesn't process all input files

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using logstash to process several Zanox csv exports and export them to elasticsearch.
However, for some reason logstash often processes only some of the input files.

The input files definitely exist in the given directory. To avoid the Logstash Inode buch I've set sincedb_path to /dev/null, stop logstash every day before the new files are downloaded and start it after the downloads have been completed.

Logstash and Elasticsearch are currently on the same server

The first file (1) is the only one that always is being imported. It is a rather big feed with about half a gigabyte.
Also the Zanox csv has a small glitch: the first line starts with a point, invalidating the csv format for this line.

```
input { 
file {
     path => ["/var/app/1/*.csv"]
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     start_position => beginning
     type => "1"
  }  
    file {
     path => ["/var/app/2/*.csv"]
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     start_position => beginning
     type => "2"
  }
    file {
     path => ["/var/app/3/*.csv"]
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     start_position => beginning
     type => "3"
  }
    file {
     path => ["/var/app/4/*.csv"]
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     start_position => beginning
     type => "4"
  }
    file {
     path => ["/var/app/5/*.csv"]
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     start_position => beginning
     type => "5"
  }
    file {
     path => ["/var/app/6/*.csv"]
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     start_position => beginning
     type => "6"
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "1" {
      csv { 
        columns => [ "title", "price", "image", "deeplink", "color" ] 
    separator => ";" 
      }

  } else {
      csv { 
        columns => [ "title", "price", "image", "deeplink" ] 
    separator => ";" 
      }
  }
  mutate {
    convert => ["price", "float"]
    add_field => {"source" => "%{type}"}
  }
  if ![title] { 
    drop { } 
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch{
    index => products
    index_type => products
    host => localhost
    document_id => "%{deeplink}"
    flush_size => 5000
  }
}
```

What could be the reason for logstash not processing all the files?

**EDIT:**
Removed CSV processing errors by doing some pre-processing. Now I got the following error in the logstash log:

```
log4j, [2014-09-11T03:41:50.075]  WARN: org.elasticsearch.monitor.jvm: 
  [logstash-17675126.onlinehome-server.info-13551-4016] [gc][young][1345505][23190] duration [2.4s], 
  collections [1]/[2.8s], 
  total [2.4s]/[10.3m], 
  memory [298.8mb]->[122.3mb]/[483.3mb], 
  all_pools {
    [young] [1.9mb]->[1.2mb]/[133.3mb]
  }
  {
    [survivor] [16.6mb]->[0b]/[16.6mb]}{[old] [280.2mb]->[121.1mb]/[333.3mb]
  }
```

Comment: Do your logstash have any warning message like 'csv parse fail'? Your config looks correct. As your say, the first line of the logs is invalidate csv format. Please make sure all your logs are in format.

Comment: I get Illegal Quoting errors on line 1 of each file, but it says severity is just "warning". And at least the first file is always processed, even though it also has this error.

Comment: From your config it didn't have any error. Please have a try do you use any filter and use stdout as the output to make sure logstash have read all  your input file.

Comment: I've added some pre-processing to remove the csv parsing error.Today I've got a different error mesage, see edit above.

Comment: @Ben: I'm a bit worried about logging stdout. The input csv's alone do sum up to ~600MB. Will take a look at it later.

Comment: That's a garbage collection ("gc") message.

Comment: How do you know that logstash isn't processing them?  Perhaps that `drop` is killing them off before they're output?

Comment: Probably not. I know that there is a title, and on some days the import works. If the drop was the cause, it should consistenly fail every day, right?